# Why is a global variable from one sub-page not visible in another?

Tags: php, global-variables

Our HTML-pages are constructed from multiple pieces being `include`-ed:

```html
<HTML>
<?php include("part1.php") ?>
<?php include("part2.php") ?>
</HTML>
```

I'm setting a global (boolean) variable in `part1.php`:

```php
<?php
        global $safeToShowAd;
        $safeToShowAd = TRUE;
?>
```

and would like to be able to examine it in `part2.php`:

```
<?php if ($safeToShowAd): ?>
<div ... advertisement ...> ... </div>
<?php endif ?>
```

Unfortunately, that does not work -- the variable is treated as empty (and thus, always FALSE).

Our php is of version 5.6.40 -- any hope?

Comment: `global` doesn't do anything outside a function.

Comment: You use that declaration inside a function to allow it to access variables that were assigned outside the function.

Comment: Show your code of `part2.php`

Comment: I updated the question with the requested detail. Yes, I tried without `global` first -- does not seem to make any difference...

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. I executed your main script, and it output the div from part2.php.